# Working with screen via another screen session

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I connect to Host1 using ssh and start a screen session. From one of those windows I ssh into the Host2, which launches a screen session on login.

How can I create new/switch between screen windows on Host2?
Is there a way to escape the first screen(Host1) and send the command to the second screen(Host2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a *nested screen session* (using `screen` within a `screen` session).

By default, to send commands to the nested session, you hit a second <kbd>a</kbd> first:

<kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> *command*

For example, to create a new window in the nested session:

<kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>

From the [screen documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Character):

> **(C-a a)** 
>   Send the command character (C-a) to the process in the current window.

Comment: So 'nested screen session' is the magic google word for this, thanks.